# How to implement horizontal scroll bar while insert value in text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of items in a grid with checkboxes. I need to show and update items with comma separated in text box when the user selects or un-selects from the grid. I have done this as below:

**HTML:**

```
<input type "text" id="items">
```

**Javascript-jQuery** (when user selects or unselects an item from grid):

```
$("#items").val(seleteditmes.join(", "));  //I have all selected items in seleteditmes
```

Everything is working fine. Now the problem is when the user selects more than 6 items, only the first 6 items will show. I want to expand text box with horizontal scroll bar. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you cant. you only extend the width of the `input` but you cant put scroll on it. I prefer you use `textarea` ?

Comment: can text area expandable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221104/how-do-i-create-a-scrollable-textbox

Comment: @umer yes. and can be scrolled.

Comment: @Abbr thanks. buddy.

Answer (score 2):

You should use textarea instead of input. It has scrollbar. If you want to be on a single line, then you should use css `white-space: nowrap;` and set a height the same as a simple input.

```html
<textarea id="items" rows="2" cols="40" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: hidden;">
Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text 
</textarea>
```

Then you can change textarea value like you did before, with the input.